# Call to undefined method PDF::setSourceFile()

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm in big trouble atm, and I'm trying to add a watermark to an existing pdf using fpdf + rotate script for fpdf. But when I try to set the source file, it prints that function setSourceFile() doesn't exist. I searched at google and StackOverflow, and many codes use this method, but I returned this error. Could anyone help me?

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDF::setSourceFile() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18

My code:

```
<?php
require('rotation.php');
class PDF extends PDF_Rotate{
    function Header(){
        //Put the watermark
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',50);
        $this->SetTextColor(255,192,203);
        $this->RotatedText(35,190,'W a t e r m a r k   d e m o',45);
    }
    function RotatedText($x, $y, $txt, $angle){
        //Text rotated around its origin
        $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
        $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
        $this->Rotate(0);
    }
}
$pdf = new PDF();
$pages_count = $pdf->setSourceFile('teste.pdf'); 
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDF::setSourceFile() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 18

Comment: Looks like it's not included in the FPDF natively: [More info here](https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-fpdf/issues/19) -- You need to install `FPDI` class extension for FPDF

Comment: Yeah... ty so much :x works here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [This resolved issue](https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-fpdf/issues/19) ... You need the [FPDI Extension](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/the-fpdi-class/) to extend the `FPDF` class.  Installation can be found [HERE](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI)